# Not expected django query set response

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm making a query set with django to list some courses. The problem is when I make the query in the django shell, it returns something like this: <QuerySet [<Course: Course object (1)>,....]>

How can I make it to obtain the table information?

PSD: I make a query set with the users table exactly as I described and I get the expected result. But it can't show the result in the template. So if you can help... Thanks for the help in advance.

```py
class ListCursos( TemplateView):
    model1 = User
    model2 = Course
    template_name = 'plantillas/miscursos.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListCursos, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['usuarios'] = User.objects.all()
        context['cursos'] = Course.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: What do you mean by **table information**? The values of each row?

Comment: @Countour-Integral Yes, table information = values of each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of the columns for each instance of a model are as stored as instances variables. You have not provided the definition of one of your models, so I'll just take this for an example.

```
class Course(models.Model): # example model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    students = models.IntegerField()
```

When you have a queryset of `Course` models you can access them by index

```
>>> all_courses = Course.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Course: Course object (1)>]>
>>> first_course = all_courses[0]
```

and to acess the values of the selected `Course` model instance you just type the names for the columns that you have in the class definition. if for example you have the `Course` model with name history and 10 students then

```
>>> first_course.name # just type the name of the column
'history'
>>> first_course.students
10
```

So to access them in a django template, considering that you are passing in the context the `Course.objects.all()` with a key of `"cursos"`. (like you are doing)

```html
{% for course in cursos %}
    <div>{{course.name}}</div>
    <div>{{course.students}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That work fine. Thanks @Countour-Integral